# How to identify compound emojis on Android?

Tags: java, android, unicode, emoji

For simple unicode scalars the number of code points indicates whether two characters are displayed as one unicode character.

However, the emoji [Woman: Medium-Dark Skin Tone, White Hair](https://emojipedia.org/woman-white-haired-medium-dark-skin-tone/) (‍) has a code point count of 4.

```
String s = "‍";
int characterCount = s.size(); //7
int codePointCount = Character.codePointCount(s, 0, s.length()); //4
```

It consists of:

- Woman
- Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-5
- Zero width joiner
- Emoji Component White Hair

As I understand, the OS needs to support the compound emoji to display it correctly, otherwise it displays the emojis separately as   .

I want to get the number of displayed characters from a string, accounting for these compound emojis.
How can I determine in Android whether multiple code points are displayed as one emoji?

Comment: What is the problem with simply checking for a following ZWJ and those Emoji Component values? I'm not sure why this particular example has two ZWJs though. Oh, and I think you also need to check for any variation selectors (U+FE0x).

Comment: The NUMBER of codepoints DOES NOT indicate how Java chars are displayed as glyphs. The KIND of codepoints does. You need to analyze the codepoints in the string to put them together into **grapheme clusters**. A cluster consists of a base codepoint followed by 0 or more combining codepoints that add into, or modify, the previous codepoint. The resulting graphemes are what get displayed visually. You are really asking to discover graphemes in a string. Look at [`java.text.BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html), or parse the string manually

Comment: @RemyLebeau but doesn’t it depend on the character set whether it can display the grapheme cluster as one glyph? I can parse the string and know that it *should* be displayed as one glyph. But I would still not know whether it will be displayed as one glyph, correct? (Thank you for introducing the correct terminology to my question)

Comment: @Manuel yes, the proper *display* of a given grapheme glyph depends on the support of the software OS/app that is displaying the string. But that doesn't mean you can't *detect* graphemes properly, even if they won't be *displayed* properly. Oh, and FYI, "Woman with white hair" has 3 codepoints, not 4. ZWJ is not used twice back-to-back, like you claim. The page you linked to even says so.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even more confusing then, why does `codePointCount` return 4?

Comment: @Manuel check if there is a skin tone codepoint present in the sequence

Comment: @RemyLebeau You were right, there was a skin tone. I updated the question. However I still get 4 code points for this emoji. Shouldn't it be 5 code points with a ZWJ between each emoji?

Comment: @Manuel ZWJ is not used to join a skin tone codepoint to a person codepoint. The skin tone immediately follows the person. This is clearly shown on the page you linked to

Comment: @RemyLebeau So the skin tone is a "modifier" and therefore doesn't need a ZWJ, got that. So in conclusion, is there a way to know whether the system will display the woman with white hair and dark skin as 1 glyph? I can parse the characters as `emoji+modifier+ZWJ+emoji` but still wouldn't know how the system displays it.

Comment: @Manuel did you check with `BreakIterator` to see how it handles the joining? Does it match how the display handles the joining? If they don't match, then I don't know any other way to detect it.